# Calculating how many shapes of specific size fit inside polygon on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, math, geometry, shapes

I would like the user to draw a polygon shape on google maps - this isnt an issue and have this sorted.
When the user then clicks a button, I need to work out how many rectangular shapes of a specific size will fit inside this polygon.

The issue I have is if the polygon is for example 6m x 4m and the shape that needs to fit is 2m x 3m, then you can only fit 3 shapes (area totalling 6m x 3m if the shapes are side by side) and leaves 6m x 1m area remaining.

The remaining area is the same area as the shape, but its the wrong size.

How do I see how many "whole" shapes fit inside the polygon?

I will upload an image to show what I mean
[image]

Comment: The image seems to be wrong. I think the green shapes should be 2 X 3.

Comment: Are all the shapes rectangles? Are you allowed to rotate them?

Comment: My apologies, yes the green shape should be 2 x 3.

Comment: And yes, the shapes can be rotated if need be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a difficult problem a particular case of a [packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) a full solution would turn out to be quite complex, possibly NP-hard.

It should be fairly easy to derive a sub-optimal solution. We can consider two possible solutions with the rectangles horizontal or vertical with them in a uniform grid.

Let the size of the big rectangle be `A` X `B` and the small rectangle be `a` X `b`. For the unrotated version we can fit `m=floor(A/a)` horizontally and `n=floor(B/b)` vertically giving a total of `n*m` items fitted in. Rotating by 90º we have `p=floor(A/b)` and `q=floor(B/a)` with a total of `p*q` items.

There will be some which the above does not give the best solution, say a fitting 2X3 rectangles into 5 X 4. If two are horizontal and one is vertical then you can fit 3 in.

---

For an irregular polygon boundary you could arrange them in rows with the distance between each row equal to the height of the smaller rectangles.

A pseudocode solution might work something like

```
poly = getPolygon() // get the input polygon
a = rectangle.height // size of rectangle we are trying to fit
b = rectangle.width  // size of rectangle
row_height = 10
bounds = poly.getBoundingBox()
offset_top = a/2 // y coord of the first row

// loop from top to bottom
for(y = bounds.top + offset_top ; y < bounds.bottom; y += a )
{
    // find all the solutions of the polygon with a horizontal line
    sols1 = poly.intersectWithHorizontalLine(y)

    // find sols of bottom line
    sols2 = poly.intersectWithHorizontalLine(y+a)

    // find the left most and right most points
    left = min(sols1,sols2) 
    right = max(sols1,sols2)

    // now can draw the rectangles
    for(x=left; x < right; x += b)
    {
        drawRectangle( x , y, width=b, height=a)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I can use the solution which works without rotating them, them I am happy not to mic rotated object. I'll simply offer two outcomes - one with the objects in portrait orientation, and another outcome if they were all rotated to landscape orientation. Many thanks for your valuable help

Comment: How would I apply the same solution to a polygon which has more than 4 sides, with no sides being the same length and no angles being same? Basically, the user will be drawing a polygon of an undetermined amount of sides, and undetermined angles, nor do we know if the polygon will have any parallel sides

Comment: I've added an outline solution for the general case.